# Getting id in database to pull same data on next page

Tags: php, mysql, database, get

I have a form which is submitting a number of values. When inserted into my table in my database, it creates a unique id in my database (primary key). How would I check for that same unique id on the next page that I send the form action to?

Here is my code for my form. I don't want to confuse you guys with all of my form inputs so I just put these elements here.

```
<form action='selectItems.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data" id='tradeForm'>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Go to next step'></input>
</form>
```

Would I append the id on the form action through GET? If so, how? I would appreciate any help.

Comment: are there any other primary keys in your form except id.....

Comment: No, I'm only using one primary key. Just the auto increment that gets put into my database table.

Comment: actually what data are you sending ... check any element in your data can be other primary key

Comment: Just a bunch of strings, dates, and numbers at the current time. No ID's are being sent via POST method. It just auto increments on the database table.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: ya u can keep current time stamp as your other unique id and search from that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

mysql_insert_id()

This function returns you last inserted id.

Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

Comment: You really should not be using `mysql_*` functions, [they are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). You should [choose](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) between [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Comment: I'd recommend `PDO` since you wouldn't be limited to a `mysql` database support like `mysqli`. You could [read more about the differences here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/). [Here is a good tutorial playlist on youtube.](http://www.youtube.com/course?list=EC23A4AFEA46A5CB23)

Comment: What if the php I am working with doesn't have mysqli enabled functionality?

Comment: Mysqli is part of PHP, so there should be a php-mysqli type package available. Check your php.ini function for extension=mysqli.so and uncomment it

Comment: @wowzuzz "If you are using MySQL versions 4.1.3 or later it is strongly recommended that you use this extension", it is included in PHP. You would need to change your DB connection, DB select, and all your queries over to `mysqli` as well. If you are running on a localhost then you wouldn't have to worry about it since PHP is upgraded by you. However you should at least learn it and start implementation/conversion since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated (no longer supported and going to go away). If you are using cpanel then you can check your PHP version at log in on the left hand panel.

Comment: Here is some more [useful information](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php).